# Cannot serve ionic3 app in localhost with ionic serve (blank page)

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image: screenshot]

hi guys i was working on a app for 2 months, its never been before. today i typed ionic serve and it gave me a blank page. i tried again again again; nothing changed.

the errors  of console is like that:

````
```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```
````

then i searched for solution on the internet and tried that:

````
```
npm uninstall -g cordova ionic
npm install -g cordova ionic
```
````

but it didnt work!

so i remembered, once i backed up my app folder before. so i tried that and saw it works. i copied that back-up folder's www/build folder files to the my up to date app-folder. and run ionic serve again. it deletes all files automatically and doesnt work?

i cannot serve my app ? please assist me guys. i did nothing to receive that error i am shocked!

terminal:

````
```
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser -
Ctrl+C to cancel
[04:35:39]  watch started ...
[04:35:39]  build dev started ...
[04:35:39]  clean started ...
[04:35:39]  clean finished in 7 ms
[04:35:39]  copy started ...
[04:35:39]  deeplinks started ...
[04:35:39]  deeplinks finished in 236 ms
[04:35:39]  transpile started ...
[04:35:43]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.1.3:8100, http://192.168.136.1:8100, http://192.168.80.1:8100
     DevApp: DenemeApp@8100 on ASUS

[04:35:44]  copy finished in 4.77 s
[04:35:44]  watch ready in 4.94 s
````

```

stops here.

my ionic info:

````
```

cli packages: (C:\Users\Uğur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0

System:

    Node : v6.11.4
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 8.1

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```
````

Comment: try running **npm cache clean ** and then your commands

Comment: Thanks but didnt work

Comment: i added a screenshot

Comment: any luck on this? I'm experiencing same problem

Comment: No luck. I restarted from one of my backups @PuyiSeverino

Answer (score 1):

Try serving your application in port 8102. I don't know how you managed it. But you changed the port where your build is available.
So run the following command :

```
$ ionic serve --p 8102
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt find the solution, luckily i backed up the project lately. I dont know what i did to main folder but my backup folder working well. I did exact same changes (updated) and its working.